# Live view in Dreamweaver only works for site root on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver

I am trying to set up DreamWeaver CS6 to show live previews of a locally-stored WordPress site so I can edit template parts and see what they'll look like. I used this tutorial to set it up: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw_wordpress_pt2.html

-The WordPress site is running on localhost (WAMP) just fine.
-Permalink structure is set to default
-Site and test server are set up in DreamWeaver
-I get a working preview in live mode IF I load the root index.php (not the theme's index.php)

The problem is that if I load any individual theme parts, the live preview will return an undefined function error. So the parser seems to be running, but DreamWeaver isn't loading all the necessary requisite files.

Edit: The error below is exactly what you would see if you tried to directly load a theme part in a browser. So I guess my question is, does DreamWeaver have the ability to do what I want? I want to edit individual theme parts while seeing what effect the changes will have in a live preview.

Here's what I get when do live preview for page.php:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-content\themes\mytheme\page.php on line 14
```

Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  249000  {main}( )   ..\page.php:0
```

Comment: sounds like its only loading the file you want rather than wp->template. try inserting `require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");` in your template file (above any functions)

Comment: David - thanks! I believe that would work, but I'd prefer not to modify/revert each template file every time I work on it. I decided the best solution was to stick with Chrome developer tools for a live view and CSS editing, and PHPDesigner for template files. I have to refresh when I modify a template file, but it might have been weird for me to expect live updates in Dreamweaver when I change PHP code (would the parser be constantly reloading everything?)

Answer (score 0):

I decided the best solution was to stick with Chrome Developer Tools for a live view and CSS editing, and PHPDesigner (or whatever text-only editor) for template files.

I have to refresh when I modify a template file, but it might have been weird for me to expect live updates in Dreamweaver when I change PHP code (would the parser be constantly reloading everything?).

There's a package called DesktopServer (based on XAMP) that claims to be able to live-view real-time template file changes to PHP code, but it's $99.

Comment: ive never used desktop server but chrome gives you what you need for css changes which is a live preview. I dont think you will find a "live" php parser as it is serverside code and not parsed by the browser, css is so you can fiddle with it in chrome.